# What is meant by "set map" or "map of sets" in this context.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading about free $R$-modules. There is a line that says "For any set $A$ there is a free $R$-module $F(A)$ on the set $A$ that satisfies the following: if $M$ is any $R-$module and $\phi:A\rightarrow M$ is any map of sets...."

What is meant by 'map of sets' in this context? What would the collection of all such maps be?

Is it just saying the function is from $A$ to $M$ and we can mod it in the obvious way to be from the subsets of $A$ to the subsets of $M$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are "set-theoretic maps"?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430311/what-are-set-theoretic-maps)

Comment: (Not literally an exact duplicate because the phrase is slightly different, but it has the same meaning: it just means "function".)

Comment: I don't think you understand my question then.

If $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow X$ is some function, then $f(\{1,2,3\})$ is undefined as elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ are not subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. So are they just saying define it in the obvious way or are they literally saying any function and why would they use this for the first time in the 11th chapter?

Comment: and are you sure....? please untag this if you are not, it seems nothing like your link to me but I could be wrong.

Comment: I did read the rest of it and that did not make it clear at all, as we are talking about "words" in F(A) it is very logical to think they mean we are sending subsets.

Comment: still not a duplicate at all, as I am asking about an exact term, and that term is not in the post you provided that I can find.

Comment: I asked for a definition, you send me to something that has the same definition, but a different name and then mark my question as a duplicate as if I should have just guessed at the other name before I posted. Then you are rude about it by assuming that I did not finish reading the sentence but of course you did not assume that, you just said it to be rude. I hope you see the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "map of sets" just means a map that doesn't necessarily bother to preserve any structure. It's best explained by contrast: a "map of groups" is a map that preserves the group operation. A "map of rings" is a map that preserves both ring operations. A "map of sets", by contrast, is a map that need not preserve anything at all.

Another way of saying it might be to say "a map of just sets" or "just a map of sets". They're saying it like this to make it explicit to the reader that they are *not* talking about a group homomorphism, or a module homomorphism, or a ring homomorphism, or any other kind of map you've encountered recently; they're *just* talking about a plain old vanilla map.